# no @mousedown/@mouseup in quasar q-btn

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

I want to add some functionality on mouse-down/up in a q-btn element in quasar 0.14.7 (e.g.: a claxon that starts on mouse down and stops on mouse up) but it only binds @click. Do you know how is the expected way to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If it is still relevant, try with @mousedown.**native**="methodName".
Tested with Quasar v0.16.